# Stormpath not automatically redirecting to specified route after registration

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, stormpath

Per the [documentation](https://docs.stormpath.com/dotnet/aspnet/latest/registration.html#configuration-options), when I enable AutoLogin and specify a NextUri, I should be automatically logged in and redirected to the NextUri after I register. However, neither happen and instead I am directed to the login page. To test that it was nothing permissions related, I made the NextUri an unauthenticated route that only returns a HTTP status of OK.

Here's the code snippet for my configuration:

```
Configuration = new StormpathConfiguration
        {
            Web = new WebConfiguration
            {
                Register = new WebRegisterRouteConfiguration
                {
                    Enabled = true,
                    AutoLogin = true,
                    NextUri = "/dummy"
                }
            }
        }
```

And the dummy route for the NextUri:

```
[Route("dummy")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage DummyRoute()
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You're doing it right - this is a bug. Btw, feel free to join our [Slack](https://talkstormpath.shipit.xyz/) if you want to chat.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug, which is fixed in version [0.9.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Stormpath.AspNet/0.9.0).

If you set both `AutoLogin = true` and `NextUri = "/dummy"` users will be redirected to `/dummy` after registering. This overrides the `NextUri` setting for the Login route, and is intended to let you redirect to a "thanks for registering" page, or something like that.